# Аккаунт на ютубе

Tags: youtube

Скажите, пжл. Я зарегистрировался в Гугле. После этого заходить на ютуб стал под Гугловским аккаунтом. Могу ли я сейчас сделать так, чтобы выкладывать видео на ютуб можно было под другим ником?

Comment: На Ютубе в правом верхнем углу нажать на свой аватар, выбрать пункт "сменить аккаунт", выбрать аккаунт, от которого нужно выложить видео

Comment: Там есть только "Добавить аккаунт".

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не по теме.

Comment: Да, погодите вы протестовать. Сейчас выясню и все, могу вообще вопрос удалить.

Comment: Ну так добавьте аккаунт

Comment: Так это выводит на смену аккаунта в Гугле.

Answer (score 1):

Открой ещё одно окно в режиме инкогнито и там входи под вторым аккаунтом.